# How can I cap off an old, partially-exposed cast iron pipe when a qwik cap won't do?

Tags: basement, leak, pipe, sealing

I'm trying to cap off an old cast iron pipe that's leaking in our basement.

The pipe used to be connected to a downspout on the outside and to the sewer on the inside, but it's now disconnected on both sides.  The downspout was removed, the outdoor side was capped off with some sort of sticky material, and the basement side was left open into the basement.

Here's a picture of the outdoor side:

[image: Partly sealed-off pipe]

I'd normally use a worm-drive rubber cap, as shown below, but only half of the pipe is accessible (the rest is hidden beneath the siding, as you can see on the first picture):

[image: Qwik cap]

**What options do I have to seal off a partly-exposed 4.7in-wide pipe?** I'd rather not use concrete, as the outdoor side opens into my neighbors' garden, and I don't want to make a mess there.

Comment: You need to search for plugs instead of caps... like this: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000R82OS6/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_i_gg4dBbV5B3HAP this one says it expands to 4.5 max, which would be I.D.

Comment: @Tyson Sounds like an answer

Comment: + for plug , I agree with bib it should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a two pound maul and break it up. Residential cast iron pipe is rather thin and easily broken.  Then repair the siding.